# Переход цвета при наведении мыши

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать переход цвета при наведении мыши для градиента ???

P.S. Еще если можно то как здесь вставлять многострочный код ? Я что то не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.color-change {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Standard */
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Opera<12.1 */
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* IE<10 */
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Firefox<16 */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Chrome<26, Safari<6.1 */
}

.color-change:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

#example {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="color-change"></div>
```